# Is there any way to get notified when some application is completely installed or uninstalled

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the notification of an application which is completely installed/uninstall
by using WMI win32_product class. Is there any other way of doing that in c#??

Comment: Your application or a 3rd party application? If yours, are you trying to monitor from *within* that same application or from another?

Comment: Is there an install log? You could check in it what value the main engine thread returned.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to find an alternative to the WMI?

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote the installer yourself, then you can control what happens on uninstall. Is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to call the install/uninstall file by `Process.Start` and wait until it end

Answer (score 0):

For general statistics information and also for install/unistall you can use [DeskMetrics](http://deskmetrics.com/), which has also free of charge option.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry, but im pretty sure you can't.
WMI is just a database of information about your computers inventory.
If an application is installed successfully or not, totally depends on the installer used by the Application.

If the installer is corrupt, it would still report that the installation went fine, but the program actually does'nt work.

Microsoft Installers (MSI) is quite reliable, since it has a rollback function. If an error occurs during the installation, the installer will roll back all the changes it has made so far, and therefore wont be shown in WMI.

Hope this cleared it up a little.

------ EDIT

Actually, depending on the scope of your project..
You could write a installer wrapper (havent done it before myself, but should be doable).

Almost any well known installers (MSI, Installshield etc.), all returns a result code, when its done executing.

If you wrote an application that executed the installer, you would be able to retrieve the result code, and by that know if the installation were success.
A successfull installation usually returns 0.

But for this to work, you must make sure that all installations is executed by your wrapper, and not directly, and again, it is not 100% reliable because it still depends on the installer.

Just a thought